# Order of expectation of maximum of IID random variables

Tags: probability

**Claim**: For i.i.d. random variables $\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, \ldots$ the following three statements are equivalent: (1) $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\xi_{1}\right|\right]<\infty ;(2) \max _{1 \leq i \leq n}\left|\xi_{i}\right| / n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely; (3) $\mathbb{E}\left[\max _{1 \leq i \leq n}\left|\xi_{i}\right|\right]=$ $o(n)$.

I am able to show (1) $\iff$ (2), and (1) $\implies$ (3). Is there any way to show (3) $\implies$ (1) or (2) easily?

Hints or solution are both welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are a bit overthinking. For the direction (3)$\implies$(1) (or equivalently, $\neg$(1)$\implies \neg$(3)), how about using the inequality $$\mathbb{E}[|\xi_1|] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1\leq i\leq n} |\xi_i|\right] \qquad ? $$

Comment: You are right! Thank you for pointing this out.